# How to remove words out of a list that have three repeating letters from a list?

Tags: python, list

So I have two lists:

```
list1 = ["sch", "ggg", "bbb", "hello", "bye"]
list2 = ["s","c","h","b","g"]
```

and the output should look like this:

`["hello","bye"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean consecutive repeating characters - using a regular expression:

```
import re

words = ["sch", "ggg", "bbb", "hello", "bye"]
chars = ["s","c","h","b","g"]

pattern = "[{}]{{3,}}".format("".join(chars))

filtered = [word for word in words if not re.search(pattern, word)]

print(filtered)
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'bye']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["sch", "ggg", "bbb", "hello", "bye"]
list2 = ["s","c","h","b","g"]

list3=list1[3:]
print(list3)
```

Output:
`['hello', 'bye']`

Comment: That works unless there are more than 4 characters like  "sssi" or "gggo"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to exclude words that have 3 consecutive instances of the letters or simply 3 instances anywhere in the word you can use one of these list comprehensions to filter list1:

```
list1 = ["sch", "ggg", "bbb", "hello", "bye","bags"]
list2 = ["s","c","h","b","g"]

# exclude 3 non-consecutive
list3 = [ w for w in list1 if sum(c in list2 for c in w)<3 ]
print(list3) # ['hello', 'bye']

# exclude 3 consecutive
list3 = [ w for w in list1 if "111" not in "".join("01"[c in list2] for c in w) ]
print(list3) # ['hello', 'bye', 'bags']
```

*note: I added "bags" to your example data to illustrate the distinction*